# How can add combined index to azure cosmo DB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I've read this document over here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/indexing-policies and I coudn't find any way to add combined index on azure cosmo db at index polices section.
Or even I've tried to add the index from robo 3T and mongo compass and also it didn't work.
it seems that azure cosmo db don't allow to pass its "Indexing Policy"

Answer (score 0):

Cosmos DB doesn't support this feature. You'll need to manage this combined index yourself. For instance:

```
{
    "id":"value1-value2",
    "prop1":"value1",
    "prop2":"value2"
}
```